# Sandboxing an X11 based application

Tags: macos, x11, sandbox

I am trying to sandbox an X11 (Xquartz) based application which runs fine if not sandboxed.
The X11-based binary is launched from a shell script stored in the bundle folder /Resources.

The entitlement for the libraries is Okay
    com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only
    
        /opt/X11/

At launch time I get the error
    Abnormal exit (code 9) : Cannot open X display. Check DISPLAY environment variable.

echo $DISPLAY gives:
    /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Ua4EJ63Uqs/org.macosforge.xquartz:0

I added the following entitlements with no change :
    com.apple.security.temporary-exception.files.absolute-path.read-only
    
        /opt/X11/
        /private/tmp/

I tried launching the application with appending "-display $DISPLAY" to the launch command
    [launch command] -display $DISPLAY

The error message is different  —> No such file or directory
    /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FullProf4Mac-aafxyuyegfuwkqcvilrribshxtke/Build/Products/Release/FullProf4Mac.app/Contents/Resources/FullProf4Mac.sh: line 558: /Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FullProf4Mac-aafxyuyegfuwkqcvilrribshxtke/Build/Products/Release/FullProf4Mac.app/Contents/Resources/FullProf_Suite/tfp -display /private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.Ua4EJ63Uqs/org.macosforge.xquartz:0: No such file or directory

However org.macosforge.xquartz:0 is present !
I am lost !!!!

Comment: The file `/Users/myname/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/FullProf4Mac-aafxyuyegfuwkqcvilrribshxtke/Build/Products/Release/FullProf4Mac.app/Contents/Resources/FullProf_Suite/tfp` is not, however - just as the error plainly indicates.

Comment: ("Check DISPLAY" is merely a suggestion, not the result of a root cause analysis...)

Comment: "The file ... is not" what do you mean ? The top binary is present and has an X11 GUI. With sandboxing off, it is successfully launched by the shell script embedded in the bundle. With sandboxing on, I get the error "Abnormal exit (code 9) : Cannot open X display."

Comment: The shell script is trying to call the `tftp` program at the given location.  It does not exist, because the sandboxing has chroot'd.   You need to either change your script to not do that or set up an entitlement to access that binary.  (You say that you have an entitlement on `/opt/X11`, but please look again at the path of the file...)